# What does unit mean in spatial reference system?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gis-principle, units

Each spatial reference system contains a definition of a *unit*. The rectangular coordinate systems mainly use meters, the spherical ones use degrees.

You can see the unit of a srs for example here: https://epsg.io/3857 .

The spatial reference system with the wkid of 3857 (Web Mercator) has in its definition, the *unit* of *metre*.
I happen to need another spatial reference (wkid of 2180, Poland) that also has the same unit in its definition.

I would expect that the coordinates themselves are measured in meters. In this way, when I measure 1 unit in one of those two coordinate systems, and I project it, I would get also 1 unit.

But that is not the case, see the results, the difference is 1.84776999755:

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2180&t_srs=3857&x=636850.0000000&y=487000.0000000

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2180&t_srs=3857&x=636851.0000000&y=487000.0000000

I knew from the start it is impossible for a rectangular projections of the sphere to have matching distances, but it's not obvious, and I have seen people making such assumptions.

So, what is the role of the unit in a spatial reference system?

If I changed the unit to kilometers, without changing the rest of the definition, how it would affect the coordinates?

Does it matter at all?

I started to think that maybe it's just customary.

Comment: Web Mercator "meters" aren't actually meters, just the distorted values that result from poles being infinitely far from the Equator.

Comment: @Vince can you explain it in more detail, please?

Comment: The units (first digit to the left from the decimal separator) in Web Mercator are meters but they do not match with the distances measured from the ground at high/low latitudes. See https://map-projections.net/tissot.php.

Comment: What is a *meter* then?

Comment: its a metre in *that* projection

Comment: @IanTurton When I change the unit of the srs to kilometers, what would happen to the coordinates? Would it change nothing?

Comment: The world would be a thousand times bigger